# ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED for my website after installing new SSL certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, hosting, lets-encrypt

My website `groceryshoptest.com` was hosted in `Digital Ocean` droplets with a `Nginx` server. I've used free SSL from [Lets encrypts certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/), I've just put few commands which added some configuration in `etc/nginx/sites-available/groceryshoptest` file and installed certificate everything was working fine.
Later I decided to move my server to `Linode`. So I've stopped my previous server, pointed my DNS to my new server address, installed everything and it was working fine over `http`. Then I again installed certificate from `Letsencrypt` in my new `Linode` server. It showed me everything installed successfully. So my problem is I can access the site from `Bangladesh` but can't access from `USA` following error in browser

```
ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
```

My config file is here

```
 server {
    server_name groceryshoptest.com;
    root /var/www/html/shop;
    index index.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/groceryshoptest.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/groceryshoptest.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

    server {
    if ($host = groceryshoptest.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name groceryshoptest.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: This domain name doesn't seem to exist. Is it misspelled?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've not provided the actual domain name. You've tried it, I'm really sorry about it. Can you please tell me what I can do in this scenario?